# Tasker "Night" profile won't exit

Tags: tasker

I have a profile set-up to activate when the phone is connected to power AND the time is between 10:30pm and 7:30am.  This shuts off autobrightness, dims the screen, shuts off vibrate, and lowers the ringer (except certain contacts).

This run an exit task to reverse all of this after 7:30am because both conditions are no longer met ... but it doesn't.  If I unplug the phone before 7:30am, it will exit the profile.  If the time passes, it won't exit even if the phone is unplugged.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar profile for nighttime and I don't use an exit task.  Since the task only runs during the time span you specify, it should shut off by itself once it's 7:30am.